# What does it mean for an estimator to be $n^{1/2}$ -consistent under $H_0$"?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, terminology

I just read a paper and there is a property I cannot find a definition for.

> We assume that there is an estimator of $\mu$,
>   denoted by $\mu_n$, that is $n^{1/2}$
>   -consistent under $H_0$.
>
> Let $\mu_0$ denote the true 
>   value if $H_0$ is true. That is, $E[Y] = F(X,\mu_0)$ if $H_0$ is true. Then, $n^{1/2}(\mu_n-\mu_0)$ is bounded in Probability under $H_0$.

My question is what "$n^{1/2}$
-consistent under $H_0$" means? Is the following sentence the Definition of this property?

Comment: Yes the following sentence is what it means.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1HQmBKMgDaMC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a definition in the context of point estimation:

Suppose $(T_n)$ is a sequence of estimators of $\theta$. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive constants diverging to $\infty$. Then $T_n$ is said to be *$a_n$-consistent* for $\theta$ if and only if $a_n(T_n-\theta)$ is *stochastically bounded* (bounded in probability).

This above is often written as $a_n(T_n-\theta)=O_p(1)$ in standard [Big O probability notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation).

One definition of 'stochastically bounded' is the following:

A sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ is *stochastically bounded* or *tight* if for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $M=M(\varepsilon)\in(0,\infty)$ such that $\sup_{n\ge 1}P(|X_n|>M)<\varepsilon$.